# Dialogflow + Actions on Google webhook request not being sent

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home, google-assistant-sdk

I'm having a little (big) problem using webhook on Dialogflow (API.AI) and Actions on Google.

I have enabled webhooks on Dialogflow, and I'm getting the requests when trying my intents on their console (on the right of the page). I have also completed actions on google integration (setting the welcome intent + auto propagating changes).

However whenever I try my app on a Google Assistant app (phone/google home/their simulator) I'm not getting any request to my server (not even a 404 one), but their debugger shows this error:

```
status": {
      "code": 206,
      "errorType": "partial_content",
      "errorDetails": "Webhook call failed. Error: 404 Not Found"
    },
```

Has anyone had the same problem, or knows a fix for this ? I know it's not on my end since dialogflow requests are arriving and being correctly responded to.

Comment: Okay, for some reason it started working alone (after waiting for 8 hours and still not working). 
Simulator took the name of the project instead of 'my test app' and it started working, before it told me that "this action is not supported". I'm starting to get fed up with these halfway google integrations and their lack of docs.

Comment: I have experienced the same thing. Unfortunately I don't have the answer, but there is a fair amount activity in the Dialogflow forums about this type of issue: https://discuss.api.ai/t/actions-on-google-integration-agent-updates-do-not-always-publish-correctly/7483

Answer (score 2):

Jo's answer gave me some hint that solved my problem.

In my case, webhook doesn't work after I turned it on for my agent, so I switched to another agent in the DialogFlow console(top left corner), then switch back to my working agent, click Fulfillment and found it mysteriously got disabled!

So what I did was re-enabled and re-entered the webhook link then click save. After that it worked.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm not marking this as resolved because I believe there are many "bugs" on the implementation between Dialogflow and Actions on Google.

Take note that this works IF you are getting webhook requests from Dialogflow console (on the right of the page) but NOT from actions on google simulator.

1) Try changing the name of the app on the "Info" section of Actions on Google and sending messages from Google assistant asking `Talk to <new_app_name>`

2) Try opening another project from Actions on Google dropdown (up right) and opening the first one after (It causes some reloading on the back I guess)

3) Try both

These have been working for me

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue where the Fulfillment didn't get saved even though a successful message is shown. In my case, I only kept only one Dialogflow tabs (closed the rest) and after clicking on Save a few times, I refreshed the page and made sure the webhook was still enabled. Then tested the app on Simulator and got a post request to my server!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the following points :

(1) you have to fill all parameters under **Directory Information** (you can find this information at Left pane of actionOnGoogle).

(2) your **Webhook** URL must be a valid **HTTPS** URL.

(3) please make sure your server is listening for post request as **dialogFlow** or **actionOnGoogle** will send POST request on given fulfillment URL.

[Directory Information on actionOnGoogle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLdM7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You might have given link in fulfillment tab for the webhook url starting with **http**. Dialogflow's internal architecture rejects links which starts with **http**. Please make it **https** and it will work. It worked for me.